# How can I create thumbnails from a multiple HTML input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-upload

I have an input like this:

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

And I want to create a thumbnail from every image that gets selected in the input (if there are 5 images, create 5 thumbnails). I've seen a lot of implementations, but none with a multiple field.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update the post accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.change` event for the `input`, you can loop through each of the files, and just append it to a div or whatever you want.

Working Example

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e) {
      $('#thumbs').append('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="50px" height="50px">')
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple>
<div id="thumbs">

</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can preview multiple files like following.

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
  $('.thumbnail').html('');
  $.each(this.files, function() {
    readURL(this);
  })
});

function readURL(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    $('.thumbnail').append('<img src=' + e.target.result + ' style="width: 100px; height: 120px;"/>');
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple/>
<div class="thumbnail"></div>
```